# Limiting classes that can extend a scala trait

Tags: scala, inheritance, traits, self-type

It appears there are three (or more) ways to limit which classes can mix-in a given scala trait:

1. Using a common ancestor [trait]
2. Using abstract declaration
3. Using self-type in the trait

The common ancestor method requires additional restrictions and it seems suboptimal. Meanwhile, both self-typing and abstract declarations seems to be identical. Would someone care to explain the difference and use-cases (especially between 2 & 3)?

My example is:

```scala
val exampleMap = Map("one" -> 1, "two" -> 2)
class PropsBox (val properties : Map[String, Any])    

// Using Common Ancestor
trait HasProperties {
  val properties : Map[String, Any]
}
trait KeysAsSupertype extends HasProperties {
  def keys : Iterable[String] = properties.keys
}
class SubProp(val properties : Map[String, Any]) extends HasProperties
val inCommonAncestor = new SubProp(exampleMap) with KeysAsSupertype
println(inCommonAncestor.keys)
// prints: Set(one, two)


// Using Abstract Declaration
trait KeysAsAbstract {
  def properties : Map[String, Any]
  def keys : Iterable[String] = properties.keys
}
val inAbstract = new PropsBox(exampleMap) with KeysAsAbstract
println(inSelfType.keys)
// prints: Set(one, two)    


// Using Self-type
trait KeysAsSelfType {
  this : PropsBox => 
  def keys : Iterable[String] = properties.keys
}
val inSelfType = new PropsBox(exampleMap) with KeysAsSelfType
println(inSelfType.keys)
// prints: Set(one, two)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, `PropsBox` does not impose any interesting constraints on `properties` - it simply has a member `properties: Map[String, Any]`. Therefore, there is no way to detect the difference between inheriting from `PropsBox` and simply requiring a `def properties: Map[String, Any]`.

Consider the following example, where the difference is actually there. Suppose we have two classes `GoodBox` and `BadBox`.

1. `GoodBox` has `properties`, and all keys are short string that contain only digits
2. `BadBox` just has `properties`, and does not guarantee anything about the structure of the keys

In code:

```
/** Has `properties: Map[String, Any]`, 
  * and also guarantees that all the strings are
  * actually decimal representations of numbers 
  * between 0 and 99.
  */
class GoodBox(val properties: Map[String, Any]) {
  require(properties.keys.forall {
    s => s.forall(_.isDigit) && s.size < 3
  })
}


/** Has `properties: Map[String, Any]`, but 
  * guarantees nothing about the keys.
  */
class BadBox(val properties: Map[String, Any])
```

Now suppose that we for some reason want to transform the `Map[String, Any]` into a sparsely populated `Array[Any]`, and use keys as array indices. Here, again, are two ways to do this: one with `self`-type declaration, and one with the abstract `def properties` member declaration:

```
trait AsArrayMapSelfType {
  self: GoodBox =>
  def asArrayMap: Array[Any] = {
    val n = 100
    val a = Array.ofDim[Any](n)
    for ((k, v) <- properties) {
      a(k.toInt) = v
    }
    a
  }
}

trait AsArrayMapAbstract {
  def properties: Map[String, Any]
  def asArrayMap: Array[Any] = {
    val n = 100
    val a = Array.ofDim[Any](n)
    for ((k, v) <- properties) {
      a(k.toInt) = v
    }
    a
  }
}
```

Now try it out:

```
val goodBox_1 = 
  new GoodBox(Map("1" -> "one", "42" -> "fourtyTwo"))
  with AsArrayMapSelfType

val goodBox_2 = 
  new GoodBox(Map("1" -> "one", "42" -> "fourtyTwo"))
  with AsArrayMapAbstract

/* error: illegal inheritance
val badBox_1 = 
  new BadBox(Map("Not a number" -> "mbxkxb"))
  with AsArrayMapSelfType
*/

val badBox_2 = 
  new BadBox(Map("Not a number" -> "mbxkxb"))
  with AsArrayMapAbstract

goodBox_1.asArrayMap
goodBox_2.asArrayMap
// badBox_1.asArrayMap - not allowed, good!
badBox_2.asArrayMap // Crashes with NumberFormatException, bad
```

With a `goodBox`, both methods will work and produce the same results. However, with a `badBox`, the self-type vs. abstract-def behave differently:

1. self-type version does not allow the code to compile (error catched at compile-time)
2. abstract-def version crashes at runtime with a `NumberFormatException` (error happens at runtime)

That's the difference.

Comment: That makes sense. So if I understood correctly, for my simple "loose" example, they're identical. But in case I really needed to impose constraints, self-typing is preferred. 

A quick follow-up though: can the `require` statement be implemented as a constraint in the trait (instead of the class)? If so, does it make sense to do so?

Comment: @mjalajel You can use `require` everywhere you can use any other statement, so you can also use it in the initializer of a trait (i.e. in the body of the trait, in the block that starts after trait name). I guess, using it in initializer of a trait would be somewhat less common than using it in a constructor, but as long as it helps to prevent strange undefined behavior by failing early - why not.